# Where can I find information about model size or model-loading rate limits when using MLflow on Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

How can I find out what the limits might be to the rate at which I can load MLflow models or the size of models I can register with MLflow? (I'm using MLflow as integrated with Azure Databricks.)

I've been looking at these two posts from the Databricks blog:

- [Parallel ML: How Compass Built a Framework for Training Many Machine Learning Models on Databricks](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/07/20/parallel-ml-how-compass-built-a-framework-for-training-many-machine-learning-models-on-databricks.html)
- [Managing Model Ensembles With MLflow](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/09/21/managing-model-ensembles-with-mlflow.html)

Both address ways to use a single custom MLflow PythonModel to wrap what are actually multiple models behind the scenes. (My use case is the same as in the first link - my "model" is really multiple models fit to sub-groups of a larger dataset.)

In either approach, however, there must be some limit or bottleneck. If I'm doing a batch of predictions, then a "meta-model" that loads the correct per-group model when it is asked to serve up a prediction will quickly send many `load_model` requests. If I pre-package multiple per-group models into a single custom model and register that, then there is only one thing to load but that thing might wind up quite large.

I've coded up small prototype solutions using both approaches and they work fine. And of course I plan to test full-sized solutions to see if they work in practice within our environment. But I'd feel better about choosing a path if I *also* had some source that described what the limits could or should be. Are they configurable within my Databricks workspace or more fundamental, etc.?

Could someone who knows Databricks and/or MLflow point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Updating with a bit of info I found...the [MLflow guide for Databricks *on AWS*](https://docs.databricks.com/mlflow/tracking.html#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20size%20for%20an%20MLflow%20artifact%20uploaded,must%20download%20them%20using%20a%20blob%20storage%20client.) says, "The maximum size for an MLflow artifact uploaded to DBFS on AWS is 5GB." The same section of the [matching guide for Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/mlflow/tracking) doesn't mention a size limit. So perhaps this is something configurable within Azure Databricks? (My question is specific to Azure Databricks.)

Comment: As per this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/resources/limits) Model Serving payload size is 16 MB and Model Serving throughput target (not guaranteed) 200 queries per second. azure data bricks don't support file more than 2GB..